# Images in storage folder doesn't appear on deployment

Tags: php, laravel, storage, plesk

After deploy my project into Plesk (hosting control panel ) images that have been stored in storage folder does't appear
I use this code to store image

```
if ($request->hasFile('cover_image')) {
        $coverImage = $request->file('cover_image');
        $coverImagePath = $coverImage->store('project_covers', 'public');
        $project->cover_image = url('storage', $coverImagePath);
    }
```

And that is my root directroy

```
-home_directory
    -public_html
       - my_project
          -storage
```

I already have done

> php artisan storage:link

by using this route

```
    Route::get('/foo', function () {
        Artisan::call('storage:link');
    });
```

Comment: Make sure that you have correct permissions to upload the files in your local machine.

Comment: I have all permissions and the images are successfully loaded to storage/app/public

Comment: Try move or save instead of store.